# How to write rspec tests for controllers that assume authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

For controllers that assume a user to be already authenticated, how should I go about writing my tests?

I probably don't need to keep testing the login feature, so is it best to just inject a user or whatever my authentication assumes somehow?

My application_controller includes a module "current_user".

```
module CurrentUser
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :helper_method, :current_user
  end

  def current_user
    ... # returns a User model instance
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include CurrentUser
```

Then I have an admin controller which has a before_action method that makes sure the current_user is present.

Comment: Devise or no devise? `include CurrentUser` makes me think no devise.

Comment: @fbelanger no devise, custom authentication.

Comment: How are you checking that the user has been authenticated? Couldn't you just create a method to sign in, similar to devise?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by writing a concern, and include to every spec which is a controller, in this concern we support some utility methods to login to the system.

So the code will be like:

**spec/support/controller_authentication_helper.rb**

```
module ControllerAuthenticationHelper extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    def login_user
      before do
        # I expect you are using Devise here, if not, just modify below line
        request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
        @current_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :confirmed, :verified)
        sign_in @current_user
      end
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ControllerAuthenticationHelper, type: :controller
end
```

So now the test will be easy like:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe MyController, type: :controller do
  # Use this method to login
  login_user
  # Now you can access current_user anywhere in your test
end
```

Now everything becomes simple! The idea comes from this [source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/69bee06ceee6280b54304928bb6e55c5064abad8/test/controllers/inherited_controller_i18n_messages_test.rb#L23) of Devise